# Could someone tell me if I'm doing this correctly?

Tags: real-analysis

I was wondering if someone could check my proof of the following:

Let $f_n(z)$ be a sequence of functions holomorphic in the connected open set $\Omega$ of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ and assume they converge uniformly on every compact subset of $\Omega$. Show that the sequence of derivatives $f_n'(z)$ also converges uniformly on every compact subset of $\Omega$.

Here is what I have written

Let $z\in \Omega$. Then $\exists \rho>0$ s.t. $\overline{B_{\rho}(z)}\subset \Omega$. Let $\gamma =\partial B_{\rho}(z)$. Since $f_n \rightrightarrows f$ it follows that $\forall  \epsilon >0  \ \exists N\in \mathbb{N} \ $ s.t. $\forall n\ge N \ \  \forall  \zeta \in \Omega, |f_n(\zeta)-f(\zeta)|<\rho^2 \epsilon$ so that for $n\ge N,  \ \ |f_n'(z)-f'(z)|=\frac{1}{2\pi} \left|   \int_\gamma \frac{f_n(\zeta)-f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^2}d\zeta \right| <\frac{\rho^2\epsilon}{2\pi}\int_\gamma \frac{1}{|\zeta-z|^2|}|d\zeta|=\frac{\epsilon\rho^2}{2\pi \rho^2}\int_\gamma |d\zeta|=\epsilon$ q.e.d.

is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. What you have done shows convergence on closed disks inside $\Omega$. You need an extra argument to show convergence on any compact subset.

Comment: If $K$ is compact subset of  $\Omega$ then there is an open set $G$ such that $K\subset G\subset \overline{G}\subset \Omega$ so if  I replace the contour $\gamma$ with $\partial G$, does this suffice for the extra argument?

Comment: Just cover $K$ with a finite number of balls..